# how to transform back the dateformat in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, date-format

i have a simple question, i need to convert back the dateformat in coldfusion, for example i transformed the dateformat in this way: `#dateformat(attributes.start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')#` and the value was looking like: `15/01/2012` and the original is: `{ts '2012-01-15 00:00:00'}` all i need is to convert it back, in the original one from this `15/01/2012` to `{ts '2012-01-15 00:00:00'}` is it possible?

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ParseDateTime() (or LSParseDateTime) function: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_11.html

Comment: Note, do not use `parseDateTime` with `dd/mm/yyyy` formatted values. It assumes US date format. So ambiguous values like `08/06/2012` will be interpreted as August 6th *not* June 8th.